# summing nested dictionary entries

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested, python-itertools

I have a JSON file that I'm reading in as a dictionary.  What I have is something like:

```
        "20101021": {
            "4x4": {
                "Central Spectrum": 5, 
                "Full Frame": 5, 
                "Custom": 1
            }, 
            "4x2": {
                "Central Spectrum": 5, 
                "Full Frame": 5
            }, 
            "1x1": {
                "Central Spectrum": 5, 
                "Full Frame": 4
            }, 
        }, 
        "20101004": {
            "4x4": {
                "Central Spectrum": 5, 
                "Full Frame": 5
            }, 
            "4x2": {
                "Central Spectrum": 5, 
                "Full Frame": 5
            }, 
            "1x1": {
                "Central Spectrum": 5, 
                "Full Frame": 5
            }
```

and so on.
I am trying to calculate sums (over all dates) for all combinations of `1x1`, `4x2` (etc.) and `Central Spectrum` and `Full Frame`, in this example I'd want to add up the `5`s.

What I have so far is this (using `itertools` and `Counter()`):

```
bins = map("x".join, itertools.product('124', repeat=2))
rois = ['Full Frame', 'Central Spectrum']
types = itertools.product(bins, rois)
c = collections.Counter(dict)
for type in types:
    print "%s : %d" % (type, c[type])
```

This prints out a nice list of all combinations, but fails to do any actual summing of values.  Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood the expected final result, but you might not need counters... A simple `sum` could suffice if you know that you're only going to have two levels of *nesting*.

Let's assume you loaded your `json` dictionary of dictionaries into a variable called `data`.

Then you can do:

```
results = {}
for key in data.keys():
    # key is '20101021', '20101004'...
    # data[key].keys() is '4x4, '4x2'... so let's make sure
    # that the result dictionary contains all those '4x4', '4x2'
    # being zero if nothing better can be calculated.
    results[key] = dict.fromkeys(data[key].keys(), 0)

    for sub_key in data[key].keys():
        # sub_key is '4x4', '4x2'...
        # Also, don't consider a 'valid value' someting that is not a
        # "Central Spectrum" or a "Full Frame"
        valid_values = [
            int(v) for k, v in data[key][sub_key].items()
            if k in ["Central Spectrum", "Full Frame"]
        ]
        # Now add the 'valid_values'
        results[key][sub_key] = sum(valid_values)
print results
```

Which outputs:

```
{
  u'20101021': {u'1x1': 9, u'4x4': 10, u'4x2': 10},
  u'20101004': {u'1x1': 10, u'4x4': 10, u'4x2': 10}
}
```

In many cases, I only used [dict.keys()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) because maybe that clarifies the process? (well, and once [dict.items()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)) You also have [dict.values()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) (and all the tree functions have their iterator equivalents) which might shorten your code. Also, see what [dict.fromkeys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) does.

### EDIT (as per OP's comments to this answer)

If you want data added (or "collected") over time, then you need to need to move your `results[key]` from the date string (as shown above in the answer) to the `1x1`, `4x4`...

```
VALID_KEYS = ["Central Spectrum", "Full Frame"]
results = {}
for key_1 in data.keys():
    # key_1 is '20101021', '20101004'...

    for key_2 in data[key_1].keys():
        # key_2 is '4x4', '4x2'...
        if key_2 not in results:
            results[key_2] = dict.fromkeys(VALID_KEYS, 0)
        for key_3 in data[key_1][key_2].keys():
            # key_3 is 'Central Spectrum', 'Full Frame', 'Custom'...
            if key_3 in VALID_KEYS:
                results[key_2][key_3] += data[key_1][key_2][key_3]
print results
```

Which outputs:

```
{
    u'1x1': {'Central Spectrum': 10, 'Full Frame': 9},
    u'4x4': {'Central Spectrum': 10, 'Full Frame': 10},
    u'4x2': {'Central Spectrum': 10, 'Full Frame': 10}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @BorrajaX! Unfortunately that was not quite what I was looking for.  I need my final tallies collated over all dates, like this:

`1x1 Central Spectrum: 10`
`1x1 Full Frame: 9`
`4x4 Central Spectrum: 10`

etc.

Comment: Edited answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks so much for your help @BorrajaX, and for not getting as confused by the nested dictionaries as I clearly was :)

Comment: No problem **:-)** Yeah, the main problem with `dict` "walking" is knowing where you are on each moment (things get funnier if you use one liner comprehensions... fun!! ). You'll get the grasp of it really quickly, I'm sure.